# Selenium can't input a text in a field on the website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to put a string in a txt-field on the following site with the following code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__':
      options = Options()
      options.add_argument("start-maximized")
      options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  
      options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
      options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
      options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
      options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
      options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
      srv=Service()
      driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
      waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)
      firstRun = True

      driver.get ("https://translate.google.com/")     
      time.sleep(3) 
      waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Alle akzeptieren"]'))).click()   
      waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//c-wiz[@jsdata="deferred-c2"]'))).click()   
      waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//c-wiz[@jsdata="deferred-c2"]'))).send_keys("This is some test!")
```

But I only get this error:

```
(openAIALL) C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\robalf\SOLtranslateTXT>python test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\robalf\SOLtranslateTXT\test1.py", line 28, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//c-wiz[@jsdata="deferred-c2"]'))).send_keys("This is some test!")
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\openAIALL\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\openAIALL\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\openAIALL\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\openAIALL\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.200)
```

Why is it not possible to put a text in this field?

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException` - is the filed enabled and are you able to enter the value manually? By the way is it as input field that allows the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are targeting incorrect node - `//c-wiz[@jsdata="deferred-c2"]`

Try to target `input` node. Use this XPath - `//textarea[@aria-label='Source text']` or by just this `//textarea`

Code should be:

```
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//textarea[@aria-label="Source text"]'))).send_keys("This is some test!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I include try-except blocks to handle potential exceptions if the elements are not found or clickable. This ensures that even if the elements are not immediately present or clickable, the script won't crash but instead handle the situation.

Try this code, it should work:

```
  # Wait for the cookie consent popup and then click on the accept button
  try:
      accept_button = waitWD.until(
          EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Alle akzeptieren"]')))
      accept_button.click()
  except:
      print("Accept button not found or clickable.")

  # Wait for the input field and then send keys
  try:
      input_field = waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//textarea[@aria-label="Source text"]')))
      input_field.send_keys("This is some test!")
  except:
      print("Input field not found or clickable.")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full script that simplifies selenium setup and uses a framework with smart selectors and auto-waiting, here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) version:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
try:
    driver.open("https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=de&op=translate")
    # This next line is only needed in certain countries
    driver.click_if_visible('//button[@aria-label="Alle akzeptieren"]')
    driver.type('[aria-label="Source text"]', "Welcome")
    driver.sleep(3)
    print(driver.get_text('[lang="de"]'))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

That script types in a line to translate. Then prints the result.